# PYTHON text coding - Reading from files and writing into them

Tags: python, encoding, character-encoding

I would like to read some text strings from file and save it back to another but I am facing the fact that the text is in coding which is not useful to me - this is the example of input file structure:

- Abeba
- abeced\xe1ř
- abecedně
- abecednictv\xed
- Abel

And the desired output after processing trough my script should be like this:

- Abeba
- abecedář
- abecedně
- abecednictví
- Abel

Here is my code I'm trying to edit to work somehow but I get only fully UTF encoded strings or some errors:

```
`import unicodedata
import re

wordlist = open('C:/Administrace/Python/inputs/test_input.txt', 'r')
wordlist_edited = open('C:/Administrace/Python/inputs/test_output.txt', 'wb')

while (end == "false"):
    output = wordlist.readline()

output_edited2 = output_edited.encode('utf-8')

    wordlist_edited.write(output_edited2)
    if output == '': end = "true"
    print (output_edited2)
```

`

I think it should be easy but I am a newbie in Python ... ;-)

Thanks a lot for any help!

Regards, Adam

Comment: Do you know what encoding your input file is in and what output encoding you want?

Comment: Check your indentations...still not totally sure what you're going for here.  Also, in this line `output_edited2 = output_edited.encode('utf-8')` do you mean `output_edited2 = output.encode('utf-8')`?

Comment: I guess the input file is ANSI. The output file should be UTF-8.